# How to check if user is still logged in? Coldfusion 9/10

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, locking, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have created new app inside of our existing system. One of the features in my app required locking process. Once user select the record this should disable an option/button Edit for all other users currently logged in the system. I have function that user can activate `onClick` (on the button Unlock) or if user logoff. This function will remove user off the record. All this works fine and I haven't experience any problems.

After while I noticed that some records are locked for more than a day. So this caused some problems. I tried to debug and detect the problem in my app. What I think is happening some users never logoff the system they simply just close the browser. In this situation function that should take care of removing the record never gets triggered. I'm wondering how this problem can be fixed.

Is there any way to check if user is no longer active? One of the possible solutions that I came up with would be to send an ajax call every 5 min for example. If that call would return false then I would remove the lock. I'm still not sure where to send ajax call. Should that be sent to Application.cfc or somewhere else? If anyone can give me some example or advise that would help.

Also I want to mention that I tried to set Application.cfc page for my app but if I click on the link of my app page would return blank. Here is example of what I have:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="Map.Application" hint="Secondary application event handler">
    <cffunction name="onRequeststart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false"
        hint="Handles pre-page processing for each request.">
        <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true" hint="I am the template requested by the user."/>                 

        <!--- This application.cfc is extending the root Application.cfc --->
        <cfif SUPER.OnRequestStart( ARGUMENTS.thePage )>
            <cfset REQUEST.AppName = "myApp">
            <cfreturn true />
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn false />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Read this.  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1131-ask-ben-ending-coldfusion-session-when-user-closes-browser.htm

Comment: @DanBracuk I read the article and still that solution is not the best fit. Once user close the browser I still don't now if there session is active. Only after they reopen the browser and access the page then I would be able to check that but period of time between they close the browser and reopen again record will stay locked. That is the actual problem. I need somehow to remove the lock if user is no longer active. Side note: my system doesn't keep logged in users in Database. This is an old system and I implemented my app recently.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Use Ajax.
Just use the native cfschedule to load a checker for logged in user.
You can keep login user details in the db. 
Once there is a difference with the db value and the logged in user, the this loads the page to end user session.
This can only work if you know when users closes the system. Obviously without logging out.

Comment: My current system doesn't have table that stores logged in users. I agree that would be the best solution but I'm not able to use/implement that at the moment. I'm wondering if there is a way to use AJAX instead to check if session is running, if not remove remove lock of the record.

Comment: Are you looking to have the browser `ping` the server every once in a while to let the server know that the browser is alive?